# I have used just-validate library to validate my form but it fails t submit the form after entering the fields correctly

Tags: javascript

I have used just-validate library to validate my form but it fails t submit the form after entering the fields correctly

const validation = new window.JustValidate('#app-form',

```
{
 errorFieldCssClass: 'is-invalid', 
errorLabelStyle: 
{
 fontSize: '16px',
 color: '#dc3545', 
}, 
successFieldCssClass: 'is-valid',
 successLabelStyle: 
{ 
fontSize: '16px', 
color: '#20b418',
 }, 
focusInvalidField: true, 
lockForm: true, 
});
 validation 
.addField('#fname', [ 
{ 
rule: 'required',
 errorMessage: 'First name is required',
 },
 { rule: 'minLength',
 value: 3,
 }, 
]) 
.addField('#sname', [
 { 
rule: 'required', 
errorMessage: 'Second name is required',
 }, 
{ rule: 'minLength',
 value: 3, 
},
 ])
 .onSuccess((event) => {
 document.getElementById("app-form").submit(); 
});
```

---

---

Comment: Please make a runnable snippet of your code reproducing the problem

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i have already done it, please check the runnable snippet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73510243/just-validate-form-validation-library-just-fails-to-submit-the-form-aftervalidt